# SwiftUI: Limit Increment/Decrement of an Integer Value in DragGesture

Tags: ios, swiftui, increment, gesture, drag

I am working an iOS prototype using SwiftUI and I'm currently working on implementing a circular joystick-like UI that controls a timer. The functionality I'm aiming for is as follows:

1. As the user drags the joystick upwards, the minutes on the timer increase, up to 59.
2. If the user continues to drag upwards past this point (which we will refer to as the "max limit"), the minutes reset to 00 and the hours increase by 1.
3. If the user then drags the joystick back down below the max limit in the same gesture, the minutes start to count back down from 59, and the hours decrease by 1.
4. If the user drags up again beyond the max limit in the same gesture, the process repeats.

I have implemented this with a DragGesture, and used a GestureState variable to track the state of the gesture. I also have an isBeyondMax Boolean variable to keep track of whether the joystick is beyond the max limit or not, and an isHourIncremented Boolean variable to limit the hour increment/decrement to only once per max limit crossing.

I am encountering an issue where, if the user continues to drag around beyond the max limit, the hours continue to increase, which is not the desired behavior. I only want the hours to increase once per crossing of the max limit, even if the user continues to drag beyond this point.

Here are some of the approaches I've tried so far:

Using isBeyondMax and isHourIncremented flags to control the increment/decrement.
Introducing a threshold for the hour increment/decrement.
Keeping track of the previous drag state and comparing it with the current drag state.
Tracking the last value of drag amount, comparing it with the current drag amount to determine if the user has crossed the max limit.
Despite trying these various approaches, I haven't been successful in implementing the desired behavior.

Could anyone provide some guidance on how I can achieve the desired functionality? Any help would be much appreciated.

```
struct JoystickView: View {
    @Binding var minutes: Int
    @Binding var hours: Int
    @GestureState private var dragState = DragState.inactive

    // New state variable to keep track of the last drag amount
    @State private var lastDragAmount: CGFloat = 0.0

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            Circle()
                .fill(Color.orange)
                .frame(width: 80 + (dragState.isActive ? geometry.size.height * abs(dragState.dragOffset.height / geometry.size.height) : 0),
                       height: 80 + (dragState.isActive ? geometry.size.height * abs(dragState.dragOffset.height / geometry.size.height) : 0))
                .position(x: geometry.size.width / 2, y: geometry.size.height * 0.8)
                .gesture(
                    DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0)
                        .updating($dragState) { value, state, transaction in
                            state = DragState(isActive: true, dragOffset: value.translation)
                            let dragAmount = abs(value.translation.height / geometry.size.height)

                            if dragAmount <= 1 {
                                minutes = Int(dragAmount * 59)
                                if dragAmount < lastDragAmount {
                                    hours -= 1
                                }
                            } else {
                                if lastDragAmount <= 1 {
                                    hours += 1
                                    minutes = 0
                                }
                            }
                            
                            // Update the last drag amount
                            lastDragAmount = dragAmount
                        }
                        .onEnded { _ in
                            lastDragAmount = 0.0
                        }
                )
        }
        .frame(maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
}



struct DragState {
    var isActive: Bool = false
    var dragOffset: CGSize = .zero
    var hasExceededMaxLimit: Bool = false

    static let inactive = DragState(isActive: false)
}


struct TimerView: View {
    var hours: Int
    var minutes: Int

    var body: some View {
        Text(String(format: "%02d:%02d", hours, minutes))
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .font(.system(size: 100)) // Big font size for the time
            .frame(maxHeight: UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 3)
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of `hours -= 1` have `hours = max(0, hours - 1), instead of `hours += 1` have `hours=min(hours + 1, 23)` (or whatever is your max for hours) and so on. Basically have validation on set

Comment: Hi @timbretimbre. Thanks for the suggestion. To clarify, the challenge lies not in validating the range of the hours, but in controlling the increment and decrement behavior of the hours based on the drag gesture. Specifically, I want to ensure that the hours only increment or decrement by one each time the drag crosses the designated limit, and this should happen within a continuous drag gesture. Despite various approaches, the hours continue to increment/decrement excessively when the gesture remains beyond the limit. Cheers